# Proving $\Box A \rightarrow \Box\Box A$ from $KG_r$

Tags: logic, modal-logic

I'm trying to prove $\Box A\rightarrow \Box\Box A$ from $KG_r$ where $G_r$ is the axiom

$$\Box[ \Box A \rightarrow A ] \rightarrow \Box A$$

I'm given the hint that

$$ A \rightarrow ((\Box\Box A\land \Box A) \rightarrow (\Box A \land A))$$

is a theorem.  I know that in any normal system you can box any theorem but I haven't seen a way to turn that into something useful here.  In general that theorem just looks like a bunch of antecedent strengthening which doesn't seem useful but I don't know.

Because of the $KG_r$ axiom I know that $\Box[\Box \Box A\rightarrow \Box A]\rightarrow \Box \Box A$ so that if I could prove the antecedent of this from $\Box A$ I'd be done.

I've also thought about the fact that $\Box A \rightarrow (\Box\Box A \rightarrow \Box A)$ is a theorem and therefore can get boxed, although already that seems like the wrong direction to head in.  But just to give it a go I try $\Box (\Box A \rightarrow (\Box\Box A \rightarrow \Box A))$ which by normalcy implies $\Box\Box A\rightarrow \Box(\Box\Box A\rightarrow \Box A)$.

I'm starting to get lost in all of my attempts so guidance at this point would be appreciated.

[Edit:  I also just derived the following possibly useful result.  Since $\Box A\rightarrow (\Box A\rightarrow A)$ is a theorem then $\Box(\Box A\rightarrow(\Box A\rightarrow A))$ is a theorem and due to $K$ we can infer $\Box\Box A\rightarrow \Box(\Box A\rightarrow A)$.  Then due to $KG_r$ directly we get $\Box(\Box A\rightarrow A) \rightarrow \Box A$ and so by transitivity of $\rightarrow$ we get $\Box\Box A\rightarrow \Box A$ which is the converse of what I'm trying to show.

... Never mind, realized $\Box A \rightarrow (\Box A \rightarrow A)$ isn't a theorem, $\Box A\rightarrow (A\rightarrow \Box A)$ is and that doesn't lead to anything.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is shown for example in Hughes&Cresswell *A New Introduction to Modal Logic* pp. 150, where $G_r$ is called $W$. (In other sources it is known as the Goedel-Loeb axiom $GL$; see also Wikipedia *Kripke semantics* or *Loeb's theorem*.) In case you don't have the book, here is the proof:

(1) $\:p\rightarrow ((q\land r)\rightarrow(p\land q))\quad$ Boolean tautology

(2) $\:p\rightarrow ((\Box p\land \Box\Box p) \rightarrow (p\land\Box p))\quad$ from (1) by substitution

(3) $\:p\rightarrow (\Box(p\land\Box p) \rightarrow (p\land\Box p))\quad$ from (2) by **K**-theorem $\Box(p\land q)\leftrightarrow(\Box p\land\Box q)$

(4) $\:\Box p\rightarrow \Box(\Box(p\land\Box p) \rightarrow (p\land\Box p))\quad$ from (3) by **K**-rule "from $\phi\rightarrow\psi$ infer $\Box \phi\rightarrow\Box \psi$"

(5) $\:\Box(\Box(p\land\Box p)\rightarrow(p\land\Box p))\rightarrow\Box(p\land\Box p)\quad$ from $W$ by substitution

(6) $\:\Box p\rightarrow \Box(p\land\Box p)\quad$ from (4) and (5) by hypothetical syllogism

(7) $\:\Box p\rightarrow (\Box p\land\Box\Box p)\quad$ from (6) by **K**-theorem $\Box(p\land q)\leftrightarrow(\Box p\land\Box q)$

(8) $\:\Box p\rightarrow\Box\Box p\quad$ from (7) by Boolean logic

Observe that even though the system **KW** is defined by an axiom of modal degree 2, the above proof uses formulas of modal degree 3. In fact, you can *not* prove this **KW** theorem using only formulas of modal degree 2. Here is the trick that was used, which is also applicable to other logics.

Consider a system **S** defined as **K** plus an axiom of modal degree 2. Let $f,g,h$ denote formulas of modal degree at most 1 in $p$ and $\sigma$ a substitution of modal degree 1 for $p$. What you can do is:

1) Choose a suitable formula $f(p)$ (typicaly *not* a theorem of **S**) and a suitable substitution $\sigma(p)$.

2) Find some $g(p)$ and $h(p)$ such that both the following are theorems of **S**:

$g(p)\rightarrow f(\sigma(p))$

$\Box f(p)\rightarrow h(p)$

3) From these derive the following modal degree 3 formulas respectively:

$\Box g(p)\rightarrow \Box f(\sigma(p))$

$\Box f(\sigma(p))\rightarrow h(\sigma(p))$

4) Then you can derive $\Box g(p)\rightarrow h(\sigma(p))$,
and you are back to modal degree 2.

This can be represented schematically as follows:
$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{g(p)\rightarrow f(\sigma(p))}{\Box g(p)\rightarrow \Box f(\sigma(p))} &
\qquad &
\frac{\Box f(p)\rightarrow h(p)}{\Box f(\sigma(p))\rightarrow h(\sigma(p))} \\
\\
\hline
\end{align*}
$$
$$\Box g(p)\rightarrow h(\sigma(p))$$

With suitable choices, the resulting theorem is stronger than what you can prove using only formulas of modal degree 2.
For the **KW** example above, take $f(p)=\Box p \rightarrow p$, $g(p)=p$, $h(p)=\Box p$ and $\sigma(p)=p\land\Box p$, then you get (7).

Comment: Interesting, I think I'll pick up the book.  Anything else on the topic worth reading?

Comment: The book does not explain the trick, that's why I presented it here.
But it does use similar techniques in several cases.
For example, if you define **S5** as **T** plus axiom
$5=\Diamond p\rightarrow\Box\Diamond p$
then one cannot prove, using only modal degree 2 formulas, that
$5a=\Diamond\Diamond p\rightarrow\Box\Diamond p$
or $4=\Box p\rightarrow\Box\Box p$ are theorems of **S5**.
But **T** plus axiom $5a$ is an equivalent axiomatization for **S5**,
from which one can prove the above without involving formulas of modal degree 3.